# AdvertisingIDの取得がうまくいかない

Tags: android, google-play-service

AdvertisingIDを取得するために公式ドキュメント( http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html )の通りにソースコードを書いたのですがうまく行きませんでした．
追記したのは次のようなコードです．
[app.gradle]

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

[AndroidManifest.xmlのタグの中]

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

[MainActivity.javaのonCreate()]

```
new AdIDTask(this).execute();
```

[MainActivity.javaのインナークラス]

```
private class AdIDTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, String>{
    Context context_;
    public AdIDTask(Context c){
        context_ = c;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //非同期で行われる処理
        try {
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context_);
            return info.getId();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }catch (NoClassDefFoundError e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String advertisingID) {
        if (advertisingID != null) {
            //AdIdが取得できた場合
        }
        else{
            //AdIdが取得できなかった場合
        }
    }
}
```

try文の中の1行目のメソッドgetAdvertisingIdInfoを実行すると，関数からリターンが返ってこず，かつ例外もハンドリングされませんでした．
ちなみに同一アプリ内でgooglemapAPIを使っているのですがそちらは正常に動作しました．
どなたか，原因に心当たりのある方，ご教授いただければ幸いです．

Answer (score 1):

公式ドキュメント先のExample implementationに記載されている通りのcatchを記載してみてください。
もし`GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException`に入れば、該当のサービスが利用できない端末（AVDで確認）で実行していることになります。`GooglePlayServicesRepairableException`に入る場合の条件が不明ですが（Google Play Serviceが古い？）、実行している端末の方に問題がある可能性があります。

ちなみにuser14439さんの書かれた内容で、実機（Nexus6）にてAdvertisingIdの取得を確認することができました。